# how to POST list of objects in django?

Tags: django

Sorry I'm new to django, I need to transfer a list by POST in django, The problem is that the list elements need to be complex objects, dictionaries every list entry should have first name and last name parameters.
I only know how to make list of simple values like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="alist" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="alist" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="alist" value="3" />
```

and then :

```
alist = request.POST.getlist('alist')
```

What is the best practice of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Have you read about [forms in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)?

Comment: Or maybe formsets? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets

Comment: thing is that in the code for values i have 1,2 and 3 this are simple items, I need to pass and handle more complex items like a person with  info for first name and last name

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you want to do, but perhaps you could your list as JSON and post that.